# How do i resolve an error for auto assign number and email trigger?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a script that triggers auto number and auto email to "on form submit".  But i noticed that if the email address provided by the sender has a special character or the email path is incorrect, the auto number and auto email stops (even if there are valid email address involved).

How to resolve the error?

## Error Message received:
ReferenceError: Note is not defined
at addAutoNumber(Code:62:2)

```
function addAutoNumber() {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Responses"); 
    var LastRow = sheet.getLastRow(); 
    var AutoNumberStart=1; 
    if (sheet.getRange(3, 1).getValue() == "Timestamp") { 
        sheet.insertColumnBefore(1); 
        sheet.getRange(3, 1).setValue("Auto Number"); 
        sheet.getRange("A3:A").setNumberFormat(0); 
        if (LastRow>1) { 
            for(var ii=2; ii <= LastRow; ii++) { 
                sheet.getRange(ii, 1).setValue(AutoNumberStart); AutoNumberStart++; 
            } 
        } 
    }

    //AUTO NUMBER 
    if (sheet.getRange(LastRow, 1).isBlank()) { 
        if (LastRow == 2) { 
            sheet.getRange(LastRow, 1).setValue(AutoNumberStart); 
        } else { 
            var LastAutoNumber = sheet.getRange(LastRow-1, 1).getValue(); 
            // Set the next AutoNumber sheet.getRange(LastRow, 1).setValue(LastAutoNumber+1); 
        } 

        // ---- Send a response receipt with the AutoNumber as a reference number 
        var EmailAddress = sheet.getRange(LastRow, 30).getValue(); 
        var recipientsCC = "email@gmail.com" + "," + (sheet.getRange(LastRow, 31).getValue());

        // email subject 
        var Subject = "Subject " + sheet.getRange(LastRow, 3).getValue(); 
        //message body 
        var Message = 'Dear Sir/Madam, \n\nThis is Your Reference Number is: <<< ' + (LastAutoNumber+1) + ' >>> ';
        // Send the mail 
        MailApp.sendEmail({ to: EmailAddress, cc: recipientsCC, from: sender, subject: Subject, body: Message });
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please post your script so we can debug it?  Thanks.

Comment: Please post the script into the question.   [format code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Comment: Do you get any error messages?

Comment: Ah, OK.  I was wondering why in the bottom of your code you had that one word "Note".  I thought it was some kind of typo which is why I removed it when I edited your question.  I probably shouldn't have done that so people can clearly see the error.  Anyway, remove that "Note" from your code and try it again.

Comment: I cannot see a line 62 in your code, neither a variable `note`. Could you please provide line 62 of your code (and preferably also all related code)?

Answer (score 0):

### If your error is related to an incorrect email path, you should validate the email and/or sanitize it if necessary

- Sanitizing can be done with [testing()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_test.asp) against a Regex expression representing a correct email address e.g.

`/^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/`

- Validating can be performed e.g. with [String replace()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) against a regex expression that allows only valid characters like `replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, '')`

**Sample:**

```js
    var EmailAddress = sheet.getRange(LastRow, 30).getValue(); 
//validate email
    if(EmailAddress !=" " && EmailAddress != " "){     
      var EmailAddress = "gre@gerg.de";
      var emailFormat = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
      if(!emailFormat.test( EmailAddress)){
//sanitize email
        EmailAddress = EmailAddress.replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, '');
      }
      var recipientsCC = "email@gmail.com" + "," + (sheet.getRange(LastRow, 31).getValue());      
      var Subject = "Subject " + sheet.getRange(LastRow, 3).getValue(); 
      var Message = 'Dear Sir/Madam, \n\nThis is Your Reference Number is: <<< ' + (LastAutoNumber+1) + ' >>> ';
      MailApp.sendEmail({ to: EmailAddress, cc: recipientsCC, from: sender, subject: Subject, body: Message });
    }
```