# Occasional Exception: Failed to send email: no recipient (onFormSubmit)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I have a script for emailing responses when someone submits a form. It works most of the time, but sometimes (too often for my liking) I get this error in my inbox

> onFormSubmit | Exception: Failed to send email: no recipient | formSubmit

The form sends responses to a sheet which contains text for the email body. This is the code:

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  var form = FormApp.openById('xyz'); 
  var lastRow = form.getResponses().length; //the length of the form results, i.e. the number of submission. We choose the one submitted now.
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('abc').getSheetByName('Calculation'); //link to the responses spreadsheet
  var email = sheet.getRange(lastRow+1,2).getValue();
  var timestamp = sheet.getRange(lastRow+1,1).getValue();
  var temp = new Date(timestamp);
  var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(temp, "GMT", "HH:mm' GMT, 'd MMMM, yyyy");
  var sh1 = SpreadsheetApp.openById('abc').getSheetByName('Results'); //link to the results spreadsheet
  
  //results of part 1
  var title1 = sh1.getRange(lastRow+1,4).getValue(); 
  var subtitle1 = sh1.getRange(lastRow+1,5).getValue();
  var sentence1 = sh1.getRange(lastRow+1,6).getValue();
  var bullet1=[]; // = "<li>" + sh1.getRange(lastRow+1,6).getValue()+"</li>";
  for (col = 1; col<6; col++) {
    if (sh1.getRange(lastRow+1,col+5).getValue().length >2){
      bullet1 += "<li>" + sh1.getRange(lastRow+1,col+5).getValue()+"</li>";
    }
  }
  var subtitle2 = sh1.getRange(lastRow+1,12).getValue();
  var sentence2 = sh1.getRange(lastRow+1,13).getValue();
  var bullet2=[]; // ="<li>" + sh1.getRange(lastRow+1,8).getValue()+"</li>";
  for (col = 1; col<6; col++) { //4
    if (sh1.getRange(lastRow+1,col+12).getValue().length >2){ //5
    bullet2 += "<li>" + sh1.getRange(lastRow+1,col+12).getValue()+"</li>";
    }
  }
    
  var emailsubject = "Your Survey Results";
  var name = sheet.getRange(lastRow+1,27).getValue();
  var salutation = "Dear " + name + ","+'<br><br>'+"Thank you for your survey submission at "+ formattedDate +"."+'<br><br>';
  var result1 = '<h3>'+title1+'<small> TYPE</small></h3><h4>'+subtitle1+'</h4><p>'+sentence1+'</p><ul>'+bullet1+'</ul><h4>'+subtitle2+'</h4><p>'+sentence2+'</p><ul>'+bullet2+'</ul>';
  var signature = "Find out more ...";
  var emailbody = salutation +'<div style="width:450px"><table><tr><td style="background-color:lightblue; border: 1px solid black; padding: 10px;">'+ result1 +'</td></tr></table></div><br>'+ signature;

  GmailApp.sendEmail(email,emailsubject, '', {htmlBody:emailbody});
}
```

Is there some failsafe I could add, or some code change I should make so it always reads the email address from the sheet? Or, maybe this should be implemented differently? I've checked both sheet and form results and the email addresses are there in each case.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You specify

`var lastRow = form.getResponses().length;`

and

`var email = sheet.getRange(lastRow+1,2).getValue();`

In other words, if you have 5 form responses you expect the email address to be in row 6, column 2 (so cell `B6`).

- Without seeing your data I can not tell if this cell contians a valid email address indeed.
- However, **you can implement an `if` statement catching an empty entry for the email**
- For this modify your code to

```js
...
if(email != "" && email != " "){
  GmailApp.sendEmail(email,emailsubject, '', {htmlBody:emailbody});
}
```

Further information:

If you want to make sure that `email` contains a valid email address, you can proceed as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62898194/how-do-i-resolve-an-error-for-auto-assign-number-and-email-trigger/62910843#62910843).

Comment: I should have pointed out the the sheet has an extra row because of the column headers, which is why there is a '+1'.

Thanks for the link, I'll look through and see if it will reduce the errors.

Comment: What ahappens if you implement `Logger.log(email)`? What value does it return you?

Comment: Most of the time there is no problem with the email sending, just the occasional error. But those occasional errors are an issue which I am hopeing to solve. I ran the Logger in the beginning while setting up the code, but have commented it out. I'll run it again when I add your code above. Many thanks.

Comment: The `if` statement above will prevent attempting to send emails to "empty" recipients.

Comment: I decided to use your `if` statement to send an email to me so that I can forward to the people concerned. I'm guessing there might be a delay between the form submission and the responses sheet populating with the email address which the script then thinks is blank. Many thanks.

Comment: That's possible, you should use the [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#google_sheets_events) `e.values[1]` instead `sheet.getRange(lastRow+1,2).getValue()`.

Comment: It looks like I'll have to investigate the event object you linked to above and email via the sheet which is collecting the results. The delays are quite long between submitting the form and the sheet reflecting the results especially where the form has a lot of questions. This is proving to be a very steep learning curve! Thanks again for your comments.